# Como recargar fragmento dentro de un viewpager al presionar un tablayout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-viewpager

En mi aplicacion tengo 2 tabs principales: Lotes e inscripciones, el problema que tengo es que los datos no se actualizan al cambiar de una tab a otra he probado muchos metodos para hacer que cambien y ninguno ha funcionado, quisiera saber si alguien podria ayudarme.

Les anexo el codigo de la configuracion del viewpager:

```
mAdapter = HomePagerAdapter(childFragmentManager)
    mAdapter.addFragment(Lots1Fragment(), "Lotes")
    mAdapter.addFragment(InscriptionsFragment(), "Inscripciones")
    binding.homeLotesViewpager.adapter = mAdapter
    binding.homeLotesTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(binding.homeLotesViewpager)
```

y de mi HomePagerAdapter:

```
class HomePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) :
FragmentStatePagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

private val fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
private val fragmentTitle = ArrayList<String>()

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return fragmentList.size
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return fragmentList[position]
}

fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
    fragmentList.add(fragment)
    fragmentTitle.add(title)
}

override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    return fragmentTitle[position]
}
```

}

Lo que deseo es que al cambiar de un tab a otro este se actualice.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena manera de actualizar los datos de tu fragmento, es llamar al método que tengas para obtener los datos cuando se crea, en el onResume(), así cuando regreses, en lugar de recrear todo el fragmento, solo obtienes los datos nuevamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
override fun onResume(){
    super.onResume()
    loadData()
}
```